# Feature selection using scikit-learn on categorical features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, categorical-data, feature-selection

I'm currently working with a dataset that has 5 columns of numeric variables and 23 columns of categorical variables. These variables are mostly nominal (not ordinal) and can contain anywhere from 4 to 15 different categories. I'm aware of OneHotEncoder but I'm worried that applying something like rfecv would result in individual categories within a given variable being removed from the analysis as opposed to removing entire variables. Thanks!

Comment: Ok but what do you want to do actually?

Comment: I want to choose which fields to select in order to predict my target variable. I'm pretty sure that using all 28 fields would result in overfitting.

Comment: ok so you want to implement a method that would tell you which are the the most important features right? you can use a tree base method for that

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant. So something like SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier() would work with the categorical features? And would I need to use something like OneHotEncoder beforehand?

Comment: no, the tree-based methodology does not require the data to be hot-coded because it determines the importance of the different features by comparing the splits on them, and the ones that are most important are those that minimize entropy

Comment: Any idea how to deal with the error message: "ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only" ?

Comment: well that is weird why you getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which implements a tree based method for features importance analysis. It will actually return you the original dataframe with only the top n features in order of importance.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

def select_best_Tree_features(df,target_var,top_n):
"""
:param df: pandas dataframe
:param target_var: string containing the target value column name 
:param top_n: integer indicating the number of columns to consider
:return:
"""
Y = df[target_var]
X = df.drop([target_var], axis=1)
model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(X, Y)
f = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
f.nlargest(top_n).plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
print('\nFeatures Scores\n',f.sort_values(ascending=False))
top_list=f.nlargest(top_n).index.tolist()
X_fi = df[top_list]
return X_fi,Y,top_list
```

make sure every column of the dataframe contains numeric values or use label encoder to convert them

Comment: Wouldn't it be problematic to use label encoder if the data isn't ordinal? For example, I have a column that contains different countries. I'm not sure it would make sense to use label encoder on that column.

Comment: which model are you going to use for the problem?

Comment: I'm creating a GLM using PoissonRegressor(). The portion I'm stuck on is the feature selection part though.

Comment: Ok but there is not much you can do... you have to transform the string values to numerical... one option could be to use target encoding but this way you have to be really attentive to what you are doing as there are high chances to overfitting... if your problem is that you do not want to increase dimensionality you can first perform data-binning and then one hot encoding... or for every feature you can select the top 3-4 most frequent values and drop the others and then one-hot-encode...